# Can I answer an incoming phone call on my Apple Watch using Siri command?

Tags: apple-watch, siri

Is it possible to add a Siri command like "Answer the phone" when I have an incoming phone call on my Apple Watch?

The use case is to be able to do that while doing any surfing-like activities with Apple Watch being in the water-locked state.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be now possible with just "Hey Siri" and "Answer the phone".

It is also possible with iOS v14.5 and compatible headphones. In Siri settings enable:

- "Allow Siri when locked"
- "Announace Calls" -> always

And now you can answer by saying "Answer" when there's an incoming call. Doesn't work with Apple Watch though.

Ref: https://lifehacker.com/use-siris-ios-14-5-update-to-answer-calls-with-your-voi-1846774139